# LaTex, drawing using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

Can someone help me to draw this in LaTeX using tikz
[image]

This is what I have for now

```
\def\FunctionF(#1){3/(#1)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis on top=true,
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=4,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=4,
        height=8.0cm,
        width=8.0cm,
        xtick=none,
        ytick={1},
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$
   ]
\addplot[name path=F] [domain=-4:4, samples=100, mark=none,thick]
 {\FunctionF(x)};
\draw [draw=none,name path=B] (axis cs:0,-4)--(axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:-4,0)--(axis cs:-4,-4)--(axis cs:0,0);
\addplot[draw=none,name path=C] (axis cs:-4,0)--(axis cs:4,0);
\addplot[pattern=north east lines] fill between[of=F and C, soft clip={domain=4:0.7}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\[0.2cm]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should compile so it should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 3):

if i correctly understood your question, than you looking for something like this:

[image]

above image was generated by:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, patterns}

\begin{document}
\def\FunctionF(#1){3/(#1)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height=8.0cm,   width=8.0cm,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top,
    xmin=-4, xmax=4,
    ymin=-4, ymax=4,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick={1},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$
    every axis plot post/.append style={ultra thick, color=blue!30},
    domain=-4:4, samples=100, mark=none,
]
\addplot[name path=F]   {\FunctionF(x)};
\path[name path=B]      (-4,4) -- (0, 4)
                        (0,-4) -- (4,-4);
\addplot[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=gray!50]
         fill between[of=F and B];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```